# How to test performance of pi as a wifi access point?

Tags: networking, wifi

EDIT I run the pi (either a pi 2 with external wifi dongle or pi 3) as servers and WAP for a local server project (no internet connexion involved here). I have noticed that the performance of the pi as a WAP if the limiting factor of my system.

I've been testing the wifi performance by connecting up to 15 tablets and measuring lags between the time the request is sent by the device and the time it's received by the server, and other way around. But it sounds like a very inefficient testing method.

Is there any alternative to connecting more and more devices until it starts falling?

Comment: Your question is unanswerable without a lot more detail. Which version of the Pi are you using, how is the Pi connected to the router, are you using an adapter or built-in wifi on the Pi 3, which adapter, are you testing throughput/latency/something else, what constitutes a 'fail'?

Comment: So you have 12-15 tablets connected to the WiFi and it still works? Sounds like test passed. If you concerned by throughput, then its simple. `(Bandwidth / (Number of Devices / Antennas) ) - 25% for noise` I have 802.11ac and it maxes out at 35mbits even though using a cable doing the same thing saturates gigabit.  For real commercial uses, you need proper WiFi routers, with multiple antennas and channel handling.

Comment: @goobering sorry I think I was not clear enough, but there is no internet or external router involved. Just the pi, set up as a WAP with a nodejs server on it, devices connect to the pi to exchange json data. I'm trying to figure out how many devices it can handle.